# Yii Framework 1.1.. CGridview filter is not working with my own search function into model

Tags: php, yii, filter, cgridview

i had clone search function into model, use it in controller pass to my view to use CGridview, the result data is correct but filters stop working, i can't see any difference so there must be something more else to add. This are the sections of my code:
Model:

```
public function searchCargo()
   {
     $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
     $criteria->compare('cargoResp',1,true);
     return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                              'criteria'=>$criteria,
                          ));
   }
```

Controller

```
$modRespSearchC=new Responsables('searchCargo');

$modRespSearchC->unsetAttributes();
if(isset($_GET['Responsables']))
   $modRespSearchC->attributes=$_GET['Responsables'];
```

CGridView:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'responsables-grid1',
'dataProvider'=>$modRespSearchC->searchCargo(),
'filter'=>$modRespSearchC,

'columns'=>array(
           'apell1Resp',
           'apell2Resp',
           'cargoResp',.....
```

what i had miss??
how can use filters with my own functions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other search conditions are missing. However since they exist in the `search` function all you need to do is call that function as below:

```
public function searchCargo() {
    $dataProvider = $this->search();
    $dataProvider->criteria->compare('cargoResp',1,true); 
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Also unless you have added rules for `searchCargo` in your model's `rules` method, your scenario should be `search` i.e

```
$modRespSearchC=new Responsables('search')
```